# How to close (pop) all the similar routes in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app I have 7+ screens. I am using named routes.
screen1 is default first page..

I have to close screen4 when tapping back button from screen4 and need to go screen3, in this case there are multiple screen4 there in route tree(back to back like 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 ). I want to close all the screen4 in one tap.

I tried below code but the context is always giving 'screen4' so it closing till screen2

```
while (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name ==
   'screen4' &&   Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
        if (mounted) {
           Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
        }
}
```

I need to pass true to screen3 so I can't use popuntil here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popuntil` can still work for the scenario you mention:

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .popUntil((Route route) => route.settings.name != 'screen4');
```

This will take you from

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 4 -> 4
```

to

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

if you have further conditions, apply them within `popuntil`

Comment: I need to pass a value from screen4 to screen3 (true)

Comment: Sorry, I understand your point now. can you use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed` when navigating to screen4 from within screen4? or do you still need the previous screen4 in the stack?

Comment: Actually these 4 -> 4 -> 4-> 4 are from 4 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4 ->5 ->3->4 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4 this state. when poping the screen5 there will be a screen4. finally there were multiple screen4 back t back 4-> 4-> 4->4 . if i click back from scrren5 it should hqve screen4, so can't use replacement there. (flow is editing some information in screen 5 will close screen5 opens screen 3 after change it will go screen 4 from there can go screen5)

Comment: Is there any way to pass a value from `popUntil`